# Как правильно делать бэкап на сервере?

Tags: администрирование, резервное-копирование, raid

**Какую выбрать стратегию бэкапа и программные средства, чтобы максимально быстро ввести сервер в работу после сбоя?**

Имеется сервер с гипервизором ESXi, на котором имеется несколько виртуальных машин, все расположено на массиве дисков RAID10 (привожу эту информацию с целью вдруг какие-то советы могут учитывать эти особенности)

Виртуальные машины (Debian 8) выполняют функции прокси-сервера, почтового и веб-сервера.

Веб-сервер содержит сайты и файловое хранилище.

**Как понимаю, следует обратить внимание в первую очередь на БД, список установленных пакетов (чтобы на новом сервере не вспоминать, что стояло), файлы конфигурации. Что еще?**

**Имеет ли смысл использовать программы типа Acronis для копирования рейда целиком?** Например, на ноутбуке периодически запускаю зеркальное копирование диска и в случае сбоя имею целую систему со всем содержимым.

Дайте, пожалуйста, советы.

Comment: а куда именно вы хотите все это сохранять? а вы не хотите рассмотреть вариант с использованием Infrastructure as Code?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman сохранять всмысле держать бэкап? жесткие диски не проблема

Comment: +1, вам скорее нужен chef, чем бэкап образа

Comment: @while1pass то есть вы собираетесь делать бэкап на диски и потом их уносить в сейф?

Comment: @Etki если правильно понял с первого взгляда, мы делаем какую-то мегаконфигурацию, которая содержит в себе актуальные данные о системе, а в случае сбоя восстанавливает состояние. В моем случае она работает только внутри системы (виртуальной машины). Гипервизор придется настраивать отдельно. Правильно?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman зачем в сейф) всегда под рукой. например, я написал, всегда имею актуальную копию жесткого диска ноутбука и в случае проблем (пускай даже физическое уничтожение), я могу за полчаса восставновить систему

Comment: @MikhailVaysman chef, который предложил Etki, соответствует духу IAC?

Comment: Грубо говоря, да. Вообще есть "большая четверка" CM - chef, ansible, puppet, saltstack - но на мой личный взгляд пользоваться из этого всего можно только первым.

Comment: @while1pass бэкапы не должны находить в том же помещении (здании, стране, планете :) - завит от желаемой надежности), что и оригинальные данные. иначе проще добавить дисков в уже существующий RAID или добавить еще один RAID. chef - отлично подходит. как и остальные названые средства.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman надеюсь, что с моей комнатой ничего не случится) и еще вопрос, чтобы не множить бестолковые темы - если контроллер выдает сообщение о деградации массива (1 диск из 4 в RAID10) и одним из вариантов дает "rebuilding". что он сделает? построит массив из оставшихся 3 (и будет ждать когда я докину в корзину нормальный диск) или раскидает области по всем 4?

Comment: @Etki если не сложно, дайте совет по предыдущему комментарию

Comment: совсем не спец по рейдам, но скорее всего попробует пересоздать диск с нуля

Comment: @while1pass зависит от конкретного RAID. по идее он не должен ничего перестраивать пока вы не замените дефектный диск.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  про перестборку спасибо, еще почитать надо. кстати, смарт-тест каждого диска не показал дефектов. или смарт не показатель и у контролера свои параметры оценки?

Comment: @while1pass зависит от конкретного RAID. но если мне дороги данные, то я бы поменял диск. но я не большой специалист в железе. тут лучше обратиться в службу поддержки, но в начале поменять диск :) я большой специалист в паранойе :) некоторые файлы с моего домашнего диска сохраняются в 3 разных места.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman служба поддержки это сильно) спасибо за ответы

Comment: @while1pass RAID обычно стоит приличных денег, так что пусть отрабатывают.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да это дома у меня) тут можно и поломать